# erlang function :verify the format of parameter

Tags: erlang

I started with erlang

and for the moment I have a function that takes as a parameter an account number

and in this function I do the test:

test if this number is empty or not
testing whether the number of characters is equal to 9 or not character

test if these characters are numbers or letters

the structure of this function is:

```
  checkNumCompte(numeroCompte) ->
if numeroCompte==null
......
```

I think that we should develop a sub function the first one is to verify the number fo charactersthe second one is to verify the format of the characters

best reagrds

alen

Comment: I edited my answer to better match your desired error messages, see below

Answer (score 0):

The usage in erlang is to use try to match variables against pattern and to use guards. For example with the 3 case you give, you could write something like:

```
checkNumCompte(C=[_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_]) -> % check that C is a list of 9 elements
                                         % you could imagine to test that 2 charaters are equal using a 
                                         % pattern like [_,_A,_,_A,_,_,_,_,_]
    Resp = case lists:foldl(
                     fun(X,A) when A == true andalso X >= $a andalso X =< $z -> A;
                        (_,_) -> false end, 
                        %% a function to test the set of character, you can call any function here
                     true,
                     C) of
               true -> ok;
               _ -> badNumCompte
            end,
    {Resp,C};
checkNumCompte(C) -> %% if the variable is not a list or has a bad length 
    {badNumCompte,C}.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following approach. I couldn't tell if you needed the account number to be only numbers or only letters, so I arbitrarily decided you wanted it to be only numbers.

**EDITED TO MATCH YOUR COMMENTS ***

```
check_num_compute(NumeroCompte) when length(NumeroCompte) == 9->
    case io_lib:printable_unicode_list(NumeroCompte) of
        true -> validate_contents(NumeroCompte);
        false -> {error, not_string_of_numbers}
    end;
check_num_compute(NumeroCompte) when is_list(NumeroCompte) ->
    {error, wrong_length};
check_num_compute(_) ->
    {error, not_string}.

validate_contents(NumeroCompte)->
    AcceptFn = fun(C)->C >= $0 andalso C =< $9 end,
    case lists:dropwhile(AcceptFn, NumeroCompte) of
        [] -> true;
        _ -> {error, not_all_numbers}
    end.

19> t:check_num_compute([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]).
    {error,not_string_of_numbers}
20> t:check_num_compute("123456789").
    true
21> t:check_num_compute([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]).
    {error,not_string_of_numbers}
23> t:check_num_compute("12345678f").
    {error,not_all_numbers}
25> t:check_num_compute([]).
    {error,wrong_length}
```

If you wanted the account number to be only letters, than a simple change to validate_contents/1 should suffice.

Also, you may prefer the following to the lists:dropwhile/2 approach:

```
validate_contents([]) -> 
    true;
validate_contents([C|Cs]) when C >= $0, C =< $9 ->
    validate_contents(Cs);
validate_contents(_) -> 
    {error, bad_arg}.
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer , I try with this code :

```
-export([check_num_compute/1]).
check_num_compute(NumeroCompte) when length(NumeroCompte) == 9->
    case io_lib:printable_unicode_list(NumeroCompte) of
        true -> validate_contents(NumeroCompte);
        false -> {error, bad_arg}

    end;
check_num_compute(_) ->
io:format("count number incorrect\n").
validate_contents([]) -> io:format("count number coorect\n"); 
validate_contents([C|Cl]) when C >= $0 ,C  =< $9 ->
validate_contents(Cl);
validate_contents(_) ->io:format("count number correct but it s not only number\n"). % if any character isn't a number than bad_arg,
```

but this code does not test if the NumeroCompte is empty or not

when it is empty I want  to disply this message :

account number is empty

and also I want to know how to dothe same thing ( to display my message (coorect,empty,incorrect..) with the second code of your response  :

```
check_num_compute_version2(NumeroCompte2) when length(NumeroCompte2) == 9->
    case io_lib:printable_unicode_list(NumeroCompte2) of
        true -> validate_contents2(NumeroCompte2);
        false -> {error, bad_arg}
    end;
check_num_compute_version2(_) ->
    {error, bad_arg}.

validate_contents2(NumeroCompte2)->
    [] == lists:dropwhile(fun(C)->C >= $0 andalso C =< $9 end,
                          NumeroCompte2).
```

Comment: The code tests if it is any length other than 9. I am not sure why you want to print out these specific error messages, I would just print out the usage (rules for correct account number) on any of the {error, bad_arg} conditions - why make the user guess the correct usage. Also, one might think my code is crap, but hopefully with very little work you can understand what I have done, it should be easy enough to modify it to your needs. If you find my answer promising, please accept it or up-vote it.

Comment: You can add at the beginning a test for that: check_num_compte([]) -> {error,empty_code);  check_num_compte(L) when is_list(L) and length(L) =/= 0 -> {error,wrong_length); ... then your version 2. Note that if the arg is not a list, length(Arg) == 9 will fail so you will get a bad_arg as expected.